# TextView Dimensions - Phones and Tablets

Tags: android, xml, textview, dimensions

I am familiar with setting different - different dimensions for Android Phones and Tablets

for an example I have used below dimens.xml in values:

```
<dimen name="text_size">18sp</dimen>
```

structure:

```
res/values/dimens.xml

res/values-small/dimens.xml

res/values-normal/dimens.xml

res/values-large/dimens.xml

res/values-xlarge/dimens.xml
```

Now I just want to know, **Is there any logic (calculation)** to give text sizes in `dimens.xml` for all android devices, like:

If I have provided `18sp` in `values/dimens.xml` then how could I understand that I have to use `30sp` for tablets, `14sp` for small devices, `16sp` for normal devices

Answer (score 2):

**Is there any logic (calculation) to give text sizes in dimens.xml for all android devices ?**

You can use `DisplayMetrics` logic .

> A structure describing general information about a display, such as
>   its size, density, and font scaling.
>
> ```
>     DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
>
>     int DeviceTotalWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
>     int DeviceTotalHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
> ```

**Now**

```
    TextView Tv_App_Title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.App_Title);
    Tv_App_Title.setTextSize(DeviceTotalHeight/8);
```

**Edit**

```
Tv_App_Title.getMeasuredHeight(); //get height
Tv_App_Title.getMeasuredWidth();  // get Width
```

**`float size = TvObj.getTextSize();`**

> public float getTextSize ()
>
> Added in API level 1 Returns the size (in pixels) of the default text
>   size in this TextView.

Now according to your question add logic

```
if(size>)
{
}
else{
}
```